# Why does my SQL Server show more than half a million active tasks?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

```
select task_state,count(*)
from sys.dm_os_tasks
group by task_state
```

I ran the above statement on a SQL Server instance, and found it had about 633,000 records.

```
task_state     
-------------- -----------
RUNNABLE       2
RUNNING        32
DONE           633115
SUSPENDED      99
```

How can I Close/Kill the useless tasks?

The MDW data collector have about 4000 page allocate in tempdb per time.

And this cause the IO pressure when server in busy time.

This is production server, We do not want to restart the service.
And the version number is 11.0.3000.

```
The Max Worker Count is :1216
CPU Count:48
Hyperthread ratio:12
MaxDop: 8
```

Scheduler_Id is 0 - 47 and the amount of rows are average.
and other columns are null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in SQL Server 2012. Details of a hotfix are at

[FIX: A memory leak occurs when you enable AlwaysOn Availability Groups or SQL Server failover cluster in Microsoft SQL Server 2012](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2877100)